# Angular 2 Unit Test Always Passing When It Should Fail

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm testing a service that has a method in its constructor called checkName(). For some reason, when I try to test the checkName() method, it's always successful, even when the test should be failing. However, if I comment out the method in the constructor, the test behaves like it should and fails.

Here are my tests for Service1:

```
describe('Service: Service1', () => {
  let service1: Service1;
  let service2: Service2;

  beforeEach(() => {
    routerStub = {
     navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
    };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          providers: [
            Service1,
            {provide: Service2, useValue: Service2Stub},
            {provide: Router, useValue: routerStub}
          ]
        });
   service1 = TestBed.get(Service1);
   service2 = TestBed.get(Service2);
  });

  it('should fail', () => {
    spyOn(service2, 'getName').and.returnValue('test');
    service1.checkName();
    expect(routerStub.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['bad-name-page']);
  });
```

Here is Service1:

```
export class Service1 {
  constructor(private _service2: Service2) {
    this.checkName();
  }

  checkName(): void {
    const name = this._service2.getName();
    if (!name) {
      this._router.navigate(['bad-name-page']);
    }
  }
}
```

By returning 'test' from spyOn(service2, 'getName'), I would expect the test to fail because it should only navigate to bad-name-page when name is undefined. I've added logging before and after the 'if' statement and everything looks normal; name is populated with 'test' and the logs inside the if statement don't execute when that name is valid.

However, if I remove this.checkName() from the constructor, this test fails like I would expect.

Why would having this.checkName() in the constructor cause issues with my tests and what is the best way to write tests with constructor methods?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't set the return value until *after* the service has been constructed and, therefore, after that method gets called. Set that up when you create the fake second service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think I understand what you're suggesting. The fake second service is just a stub in which I'm telling it to return 'test' using .returnValue(). Do you have an example of what you're recommending?